# Can see lens flare through moving object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why do my lens flare (coming from a directional light, using the lens flare component on main_camera) is showing through my object ONLY when moving ?

My spaceship has a mesh collision component. The glass and the ship model are separated, so the lens flare is showing through the glass as expected.

In the following images, the lens flare is behind that window frame thing.
[image]
When not moving

[image]
When moving

Thank you!

Note: I'm not moving at insane speed. Only 0.1 per tick.